# How to compare two times with AM OR PM formate in android

Tags: android, time, compare, datetime-format

I want to compare two times like 12AM and 1AM. I have made following function to do this

```
public int timeValidation(){
    String stTime=btn_srt_time.getText().toString();
    String endtime=btn_end_time.getText().toString();

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");

     Date date1;
     Date date2;
    try {

        date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(stTime);         
        System.out.println("================== date1=================="+date1);

        date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(endtime);
        System.out.println("===========> date 2 ==============>"+date2);            

        return date1.compareTo(date2);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;

 }
```

It gives me right answer when comparison is between 12:00AM and 12:45AM.
But when I am comparing 12:00AM and 1:00AM it says 1:00AM is before 12:00AM
pls help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a`.

`HH` will be the hour in day (0-23) whereas `hh` will be the hour in AM/PM (1-12). Thus with your date format 02:30:00 will be parsed as just that instead of being converted to the PM version (which in hour of day would be 14:30:00).
for more reference a look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm)

Comment: I set parse formate like SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");  and getting exception like java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "27-3-2014 12:00AM" (at offset 15)

Answer (score 0):

```
Date time1, time2; 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");

Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
// 12:00 AM
cal1.set(0, 0, 0, 00, 00);

Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
// 01:00 AM
cal2.set(0, 0, 0, 01, 00);

try {
            time1 = sdf.parse((String) DateFormat.format("hh:mm aaa", cal1));
            time2 = sdf.parse((String) DateFormat.format("hh:mm aaa", cal2));
        }catch (Exception e){}

if(time2.after(time1)){
 //time2 is greater
}else if(time2.before(time1)){
//time1 is greater
}else{
//both time is equal
}
```